# Seeking Variables Codebook for Merged 2018-2019 PP College Score Card Data

Tags: data-request, collegescorecard

Can anyone direct me to where I can access the Variables Codebook for the Merged 2018-2019 PP College Score Card Data? It would be most helpful to connect with this resource by 11/18/2020.

Answer (score 0):

The data dictionary for the Scorecard data can be found [here](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/) under the link Data Dictionary. You will be interested in the tab "institution_data_dictionary" of the excel file.